# How to remove perl script process taking up CPU

Tags: centos, malware, perl

I've got a process running on my server (CentOS 5.2) that is taking up 99-100% of my CPU.  The ps command reveals the name fakeproc as follows:

```
30571 ?        R    3620:06 fakeproc
```

Running top shows me that it's a perl script that is associated with this process:

```
30571 apache    25   0  6292 3044 1288 R  100  0.1   3621:44 perl
```

I tried to investigate, but didn't get much info on the location of the perl script:

```
$ ps -p 30571 -o command
COMMAND
fakeproc
```

I'm pretty sure I've got some malware (a perl script of some kind) that is creating this fakeproc, but I have no idea how to locate it or how to remove it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First find out who is launching what. The following command will show which process has launched the script

```
ps xjf -C fakeproc
```

You should then be able to kill the relevant processes using

```
kill PID
```

Where PID is the process ID in question. According to [this site](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/perl/threads/342516/hacker-perl-script-on-my-server) and [this one](http://itecsoftware.com/tag/fakeproc), what you are seeing could well be malware.

Comment: Yes, I've seen those sites. My problem is in trying to find where the perl script is actually located.  I killed the process already, so that's no longer there to help.

Comment: I assume you have tried searching for it.  It might have left a trace somewhere, try `grep -r /var/log`.

Comment: I ended up searching through all my public files for the string fakeproc, thinking that would certainly show up somewhere in the script (`grep -r 'fakeproc'`).  Sure enough, it did.

Perhaps the filenames will be useful to someone else--mine were named nakal.txt and nakal.txt.1.

Some more digging led me to believe this was all done through the TimThumb exploit of WordPress on a site hosted on the server.